# $\mathbb{N}$ as a vector field over an arbitrary field.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In one of my assignments in Linear Algebra, there was the exercise

> Show that $\mathbb{N}$ has a natural structure of a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. Generalize by proving that any set with cardinality $\aleph_0$ can be seen as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.

If I'm not wrong, we can easily construct $\oplus:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$  and $\odot:\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ by "borrowing" the operations in $\mathbb{Q}$, defining

\begin{equation}
m\oplus n=\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(m)+\varphi(n))\quad\text{and}\quad q\odot m = \varphi^{-1}(q\cdot \varphi(m)),
\end{equation}

where $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$, $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $\varphi$ is any bijection $\varphi:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Q}$ (such a bijection exists by $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ having the same cardinality). The generalization part, I think, goes by the same argument. Anyway, this bijection argument obviously wouldn't work if the field didn't have a cardinality $\aleph_0$. That got me thinking: is it possible for $\mathbb{N}$ to be a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space over an arbitrary field $\mathbb{K}$ (including finite fields and uncountable fields)? In general, is there any restriction on the cardinality of the set $V$ and the field $\mathbb{K}$ for $V$ to be a legitimate $\mathbb{K}$-vector space?

Comment: Your idea on $\oplus$ and $\odot$ seems reasonable, and I guess that that's what you're meant to do. But I wouldn't call that "natural".

Comment: In order to be natural, you shouldn't be making reference to unspecified bijections.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, I think the word "natural" wasn't used necessarily in a mathematical sense. The exercise was in Portuguese, so maybe I just translated it badly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the last question, if $|V| > 1$ then, once $V$ becomes a vector space it contains at least one non-zero vector $v$. Then $c \to cv$ is an injection from $\mathbb K$ to $V$ and hence $|V| \geq | \mathbb K |$.

You can use the Zorn's Lemma to show that, if $|V| \geq | \mathbb K |$, then $V$ admits an (unnatural) vectors space structure over $\mathbb K$.

Comment: @JoãoMatheusLealdeFreitas N. S. has argued that if $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{K}$ and $|V|>1$, then $|V|\geq |\mathbb{K}|$. It follows (the contrapositive!) that if $1<|V| < |\mathbb{K}|$, then it is impossible to give $V$ the structure of a vector space over $\mathbb{K}$. So no, $\mathbb{Q}$ cannot be given the structure of a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @MatheusL.deFreitas Exactly what Alex said. The contrapositive says that when $1 < |V| < |\mathbb K|$ then it is impossible to make $V$ as a vector space over $\mathbb K$. So $\mathbb Q$ cannot be a $\mathbb R$ vector space.